Assembler messages: Fatal error: unknown option `-g2' when using platformio with custom startup file
I have a PlatformIO project which should be flashed using the OpenBLT bootloader. To integrate the bootloader, I generated and customized a startup file using Cube IDE, including reserving memory for the checksum. I also changed the position and size of the FLASH memory like the instruction says on the Website. This setup worked perfectly, and I was able to flash the program with the bootloader without issues.
However, recently, this no longer works. Flashing with the bootloader no longer succeeds, and even direct flashing via the debugger (J-Link) fails. Additionally, when I try to build the program in debug mode, I encounter the following error:
Assembler messages: Fatal error: unknown option '-g2'
I have not changed the configuration or setup recently. What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it?
Here are the important excerpts from the platformio.ini and startup file:
[base]
extends = env
board = nucleo_h743zi
board_build.ldscript = ldscripts/STM32H743ZITX_FLASH.ld
debug_tool = jlink
upload_protocol = jlink


build_flags =
  ${env.build_flags}
  -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16
  -mfloat-abi=softfp
  -Ilib/FreeRTOS/include
  -Ilib/FreeRTOS/CMSIS_RTOS_V2
  -Ilib/FreeRTOS/portable/GCC/ARM_CM4F
  -Iinclude
  -DDATA_IN_D2_SRAM

[env:env_blt]
extends= base
board_build.ldscript = ldscripts/STM32H743VITX_FLASH_BLT.ld
build_flags =
  ${spatz_base.build_flags}
  -Iboards/myboard
  -DECU_HW_TYPE=ECU_HW_TYPE_BOARD
  -DECU_CFG=ECU_CFG_
extra_scripts = post:srecGen.py

  .word     CRS_IRQHandler                    /* Clock Recovery Global Interrupt */
  .word     ECC_IRQHandler                    /* ECC diagnostic Global Interrupt */
  .word     SAI4_IRQHandler                   /* SAI4 global interrupt      */
  .word     0                                 /* Reserved                   */
  .word     0                                 /* Reserved                   */
  .word     WAKEUP_PIN_IRQHandler             /* Interrupt for all 6 wake-up pins */
  .word       0x55AA11EE

I tried to check if the right Startupfile was used, by printing out the .elf file with readelf firmware.elf.
Another solution I tried was to delete the previously insertet line .word 0x55AA11EE.
Unfortunately this gives me the same error.
